# Having a shared Object between Activity and Fragment: Runtime changes?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have an Activity called `BaseActivity`, hosting multiple fragments.

The `BaseActivity` has a public field `Object o`which is accessed by the fragments by calling `Object o = ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).o;` This is initialized in the fragments `onCreate`.

This works but I have problems with runtime configuration changes. It seems that the Fragments `onCreate` is called before the `BaseActivitys` `onCreate`, so I cant retain the Object from the `Bundle` i saved in `onSaveInstanceState`.

Is there a way I can make sure the acitivty can retain its object from the saved Bundle before the Fragment tries to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ..

```
 @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Object o = ((BaseActivity) getActivity()).o;
}
```

This makes sure that the activity's onCreate has completed executing.